# Неоднозначное вычисление выражений в Perl 6

Tags: perl

Выражения типа:

```
print -32.0**-0.2;
```

и

```
print (-32.0)**(-0.2);
```

считаются по-разному. Почему?

Comment: У возведения в степень приоритет выше, чем у унарного минуса. И по скереиу замечу, что отрицательное значения во многих языках программирования задать невозможно. Вы задаете положительное число и оператор унарного минуса, который делает его отрицательным